# Linear Independence for Vectors of Cosine Values

Tags: matrices, trigonometry

For every integer  $n\geq3$ define an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ using the following row vector as the first row: $(c_0,c_1,c_2,\ldots, c_{n-1})$ where $c_k=\cos (2\pi k/n)$.

The subsequent rows are obtained as cyclic shifts. This matrix seems to be always of rank 2.

Actually I was working with some families of  representations of dihedral groups, arising in another context and was computing the degrees of the representations. That calculation implied this matrix should be of rank 2.
But definitely there must be some direct way of doing it.

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish it?

Comment: You may want to read this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Comment: @angryavian: Thanks.  A quick glance tells me that the solution is more algebraic (with gcd of polynomials). This is easier to deal for me than explicit computations!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The identity

$\cos((n+1)x)
=2\cos(x)\cos(nx)-\cos((n-1)x)
$
shows that each column
is a linear combination
of the previous two columns,
so the rank is 2.

This also holds for $\sin$.

Comment: [+1] Very nice answer !

Comment: Pleasantly simple answer!

Comment: That identity has stuck in my mind since reading a numerical analysis book many years ago written by Henrici. It is quite stable and used to create a relatively simple method of computing the points on a circle.

Comment: A version of this identity gives first order Chebyshev polynomials recurrence relationship.

Comment: True. Useful observation.

Answer (score 3):

A typical cyclic shift is
$$(c_k,c_{k+1},\ldots,c_{k+n-1})$$
noting that $c_n=c_0$, $c_{n+1}=c_1$ etc.
This is the real part of the complex vector
$$(\zeta^k,\zeta^{k+1},\ldots,\zeta^{k+n-1})$$
where $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/n)$. Thus
\begin{align}
(c_k,c_{k+1},\ldots,c_{k+n-1})
&=\frac12(\zeta^k,\zeta^{k+1},\ldots,\zeta^{k+n-1})
+\frac12(\zeta^{-k},\zeta^{-k-1},\ldots,\zeta^{-k-n+1})\\
&=\frac{\zeta^k}2(1,\zeta,\ldots,\zeta^{n-1})
+\frac{\zeta^{-k}}2(1,\zeta^{-1},\ldots,\zeta^{-n+1}).
\end{align}
Each row is a linear combination of the two vectors
$(1,\zeta,\ldots,\zeta^{n-1})$ and $(1,\zeta^{-1},\ldots,\zeta^{-n+1})$
so the matrix has rank $\le2$.

Comment: +1 I like this answer too. Unfortunately I can accept only one.

Comment: [+1]...And the rank is exactly 2 because the two first columns are clearly not dependent.

Comment: An even simpler presentation of your solution would be $A=\tfrac12 B^TB$ where $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&\zeta&\ldots&\zeta^{n-1}\\
1&\zeta^{-1}&\ldots&\zeta^{-n+1}\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

A third way to realize this is to treat it as matrix representation of convolution. Such a matrix is [circulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) and has always an eigensystem of complex exponentials. So we can even explicitly calculate the linear combination with Euler's formulas for relation between complex exponential and sin and cos:

$$\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\\\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$